# AutoMapper alternatives for medium trust hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I am using AutoMapper for mapping between my domain models and view models.  My web host only supports medium trust so AutoMapper will not work.  Are there any other suggestions for good mappers like AutoMapper that can run in medium trust?

I don't have access to IIS at the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can develope a simple mapper like this, if your model use properties with the same name:

```
public static class Mapper {

        /// <summary>
        /// Copy all not null properties values of object source in object target if the properties are present.
        /// Use this method to copy only simple type properties, not collections.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">source object</param>
        /// <param name="target">target object</param>
        private static void SimpleCopy(object source, object target)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in source.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                object propValue = pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(source, null);
                if (propValue != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo pit = GetTargetProperty(pi.Name, target);
                        if (pit != null) pit.GetSetMethod().Invoke(target, new object[] { propValue });
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { /* do nothing */ }
                }
            }
        }

        private static PropertyInfo GetTargetProperty(string name, object target) 
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in target.GetType().GetProperties()) 
            {
                if (pi.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) return pi;
            }
            return null;
        }


}
```